# Weblogic : config.cmd doesn't work when Starting the Configuration Wizard

Tags: weblogic

I started installing Weblogic and am trying to get the Wizard set up.

However, when I run `config.cmd`, I get this error: `\Java\jdk1.8.0_201 était inattendu`.

Any help will be appreciated please!

Answer (score 0):

you should have spaces in your JAVA_HOME env var. Use double quotes set JAVA_HOME="C:..."